# How do I make a lobby card with LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

Trying to make something like this:

[image: Lobby card]

With either a small white margin or none at all. If I choose to get rid of the margin altogether, it will look similar to this:

[image: Lobby card]

I have tried the `wallpaper` package, and `includegraphics` ... but I can't get the placement of the text to work. I have decided not to post an MWE as I believe it would only make things more confusing. Hope someone can help!

EDIT: Adding an MWE per request. You'll need an image named `FOO`(.jpg/png/pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\centerline{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=\paperwidth]{FOO}}

Text I want under the image

\end{document}
```

Comment: While a minimal example may seem to you to make things more confusing, it will help everyone else by showing what size you intend this to be and give people some code to start with. I for one have no idea what a 'lobby card' is.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution uses three `minipage`, with the optional argument `b` to make them align to each other at the bottom.

Note that when only specifying the width or the height for`includegraphics`, using `keepaspectratio` is unnessasary.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\scshape

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.85\textheight]{example-image-a}
\centering%
\large%
Junko Minori

\vfill

\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
  {\scriptsize%
  written and directed by}

  \small%
  white dolemite

  \& alessandro `saseko' motajima
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
  \centering%
  \resizebox{!}{0.8cm}{sendo}%
  \vspace{8pt}

  \resizebox{!}{0.8cm}{senshi}



\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
  \raggedleft%
  \hfil\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}%
\end{minipage}

\small%
a violent movie association motion picture feature

\end{document}
```